# What Cabal version should I have for my inter-release development branch?

Tags: version-control, cabal, hackage

I have a (potentially public) development branch for a Haskell project that I also release to Haddock. The head of my release branch always (naturally) has a `.cabal` file with a version corresponding to the current Haddock version.

But what version should I have in the `.cabal` file on my development branch? For example, after releasing version `0.1.2.6` on Hackage, no subsequent commit anywhere (esp. along a development branch) is version `0.1.2.6`, nor are they (yet) `0.1.2.7`. What version should such commits be? Is there a standard practice, either for Hackage in particular, or source control in general (recalling that Cabal imposes restrictions on the values that `version` can take)?

Answer (score -1):

I can't see restrictive [rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.10.2/docs/html/Cabal/authors.html#general-fields) for `version` field

> The package version number, usually consisting of a sequence of natural numbers separated by dots.

thus - you *can* use free-form version, and for Git-repos [git describe](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) is good choice as an identifier of any changeset, and this data can be inserted into versioned file with [smudge|clean filters](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=smudge%20clean%20filters)

**Note:**

If "only numeric" is a must for you, you can

- Follow Semantic versioning
- Use unique (incrementing?) version

but `git describe`+filter pair **become "a must"**, not "possible" choice

`1.0.4-14-g2414721` is converted into (you can, probably, lost *unique identification* of changeset in case of branchpoint inbeetwen, but...) `1.0.4.14` and such version will be:

- correct for you
- usable for identification of originating changeset
- easily obtained (automatically) from `git describe`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear what I meant my "restrictive": it has to be a number — i.e., it can't be something obviously descriptive like `0.1.2.6++` or `0.1.2.6->7dev`.  I suppose I could just use `0.0.0.0`, but the question is really about whether there is a standard practice, esp. on *Hackage*.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius - "Standard practice" is widely-accepted [Semantic versioning](http://semver.org/). You can adopt it to your needs

Comment: The question is about what valid value to provide in `.cabal` between Hacakge releases on a development branch. It can't be any past or future Hackae release version, and it must be "a sequence of natural numbers separated by dots". I've always used semantic version internally, and that's really part of the question: how do people "adapt it to" *Hacakge*. (This answer seems to be ignoring that context.)

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius - isn't "1.0.4 - 1.0.4.1 - 1.0.4.2 - ... - 1.0.5" line OK for you?

Comment: Given that I have, say `0.1.2.6`, for example, and that the next Hackage release will be `0.1.2.7`, how should I number interim versions in my `.cabal`? Remember that this must build, and must install (with `cabal install`) for people who download the development branch.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius - `0.1.2.6.*` (note - I know nothing about possible additional build-install limitations)

Comment: "I know nothing about possible additional build-install limitations" — but *that's the question*!

Comment: I've removed the tags that were confusing.